# Spring Security custom OIDC User Service never gets called

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Using Spring Security 5.8.5 (w/o Boot) I'm unable to get into a custom OIDC User Service.
This is my current config:

```java
http.oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
  .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo.oidcUserService(myCustomOidcUserService)));
```

The default authentication provider is a `ProviderManager` which checks all Providers in a loop and getting the first `Authentication` object possible.

The problem here: Checking `OAuth2LoginConfigurer` the [OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider is applied before](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.8.5/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer.java#L330) the [OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider gets applied](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.8.5/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/client/OAuth2LoginConfigurer.java#L344). Resulting in the OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider returning an `Authentication` object first (since both are supporting the `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationToken`).

That's why my custom OIDC User Service never gets called. Is there anything I'm missing in my config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just missed to set the "openid" scope for the client registration.
As explained here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/5.8.5/oauth2/oauth2-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/authentication/OAuth2LoginAuthenticationProvider.java#L95-L103